# How to reference an Instantiated object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have a weapon that I want to instantiate an object (In this case a bullet), then wait until that bullet has hit an object before the weapon is allowed to instantiate another object.

I am currently doing this by having this on the weapon script:

```
public class weaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{
        public gameobject projectilePrefab;
        public bool launchable;

        void Update{
        if(launchable){
             Instantiate(projectilePrefab, firePoint.transform.position, transform.rotation);
             launchable = false;
        }
    }
```

And this on the bullet script:

```
public class projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
        weaponScript.launchable = true;
    }
}
```

This would work perfect for my needs, however this doesn't work because the projectile has no definition of what `weaponScript` is, therefore it can't set the `launchable` variable on the `weaponScript` to true.

I could use the FindObjectOdType() function, and that works when you have one weapon in the scene, but once you have more than one weaponScript in the scene at a time, you start to having problems determining who is who.

Is there a way for the weaponScript to set itself as a variable when it instantiates an object so it would be like:

```
public class weaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{
        public gameobject projectilePrefab;
        public bool launchable;

        void Update{
        if(launchable){
             Instantiate(projectilePrefab, firePoint.transform.position, transform.rotation);
             [InstanciatedObjectHere].parentWeapon = this.gameobject;
             launchable = false;
        }
    }
```

That way all the projectile has to do is:

```
public class projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
        parentWeapon.launchable = true;
    }
}
```

## Solution:

I know Pastebin won't keep the script forever, so I'm going to put the answer here as an edit: (plus it makes it easier for some else who might stumble upon this to read)

I followed Peridis's answer, but it didn't work immediately, so I ended up tweaking it and came up with this:

```
public class weaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{
        public gameobject projectilePrefab;
        public bool launchable;
        private projectile projectileScript;

        void Update{
        if(launchable){
            GameObject projectileIntantiated = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, firePoint.transform.position, transform.rotation);
            projectileScript = projectileIntantiated.GetComponent<projectile>();
            projectileScript.parentWeapon = this.gameObject.GetComponent<weaponScript>();
            launchable = false;
        }
    }




public class projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public weaponScript parentWeapon;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
        parentWeapon.launchable = true;
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help Peridis!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a variable of type GameObject when Instantiating the projectile

```
GameObject projectileIntantiated = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, firePoint.transform.position, transform.rotation);
projectileIntantiated.GetComponent<projectile>().parentWeapon = this.gameobject;
```

Comment: Your answer got me close enough to a solution to get it working, Thank you! Without you help I wouldn't have been able to figure it out.

For documentation purposes though, I'll note that to get it working, I had to change `parentWeapon`, so that you have a reference the script, not the gameobject. So I made `parentWeapon` a reference to `weaponScript` instead of a gameobject. Then a made another reference variable called `projectileScript` that references the Projectile's script. And then I had to add some code to your answer, in the end it looked like this: https://pastebin.com/Q4Tgrja1

Comment: @JhonPiper You are right, I focused on the main issue and by looking at your code I forgot the script reference. I am glad you solved the problem. Fredrik Schön edited my answer, so I believe it is correct now.

Comment: It does appear Fredrik Schön's edit to the answer gets the same result what what I had to add in myself. Thank you both!